# Server Not Foud Issue in Windows based application

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, web-applications

I am using **HIOX Server** & for Domain name I am using **1&1**

I am facing some abnormal issues with my website. Till morning my website was working great but from morning I get SERVER NOT FOUND problem.

But If I visit the same website from my moblie phone then I am not facing any issue.

Site might not be accessible by other my client as well so what should I can do that all the users who visited my websites they can see my website.

Please help me.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but it looks like you have a problem with the network. If you are using a computer with a wireless card. Sometimes a neighbor attaches a new access point on the same channel as you. Then there is a conflict, and the network is not working properly. Sometimes I get there on time.

It is difficult to diagnose the cause of a distance so if this is not the right answer let me know.

Comment: No Sir I am Using Wired Connection Internet

Comment: The next idea I have, maybe a problem with the DNS. Because your phone is working and customers see your site I think it is a problem with name resolution on the network. 
Let's try to use the nslookup command in the Command Prompt (as administrator if you use Windows Vista or later). 
As a precaution, given the command. 
nslookup your.server.name . If you are able to browse other websites this problem may be your domain.